# Azure webhook triggers a IoT Hub

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-function-app, azure-webhooks

I want to make a webhook that can be triggered by either get/post and triggers connected IoT devices to a WebSocket.
So, I thought Azure might help to automize this process, instead of writing everything from scratch and run it on a webserver.

I am very new in the Azure world, I found it very complicated to make it working on Azure.

Can you point me to any simple to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to decide where you want to connect your devices to. Generally, you'll either use Azure IoT Hub or IoT Central (which uses an IoT Hub anyway). Your question doesn't include any details about your devices, or whether you're developing them yourself, but I'll assume you can connect to either.

If you go for Azure IoT Central, the easiest way to get a webhook going is to create a Logic App and link nodes together to trigger a [Command to your device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-configure-rules-advanced?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034). You can use an HTTP request as the trigger, and use the built-in IoT Central node to trigger your command, example:
[image: Execute a device command]

If you end up connecting your devices to IoT Hub, you can use Direct Methods, Cloud to Device messages or even Device Twins to communicate with your devices. You can leverage these by creating an Azure Function with an HTTP trigger, and you program the logic to call IoT Hub, which will communicate with your devices. There are a lot of samples on the web that show how to create Functions, or control your [device remotely](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-control-device-dotnet?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034).

There are a lot of ways to go about your scenario, if you need some help from the Microsoft community, you can get a lot of help on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/azure-iot-central.html?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034).

Update based on the comments:
In this case, the devices are connected to IoT Hub. You can use the Service SDK to run a job that fires a Direct Method to all currently connected devices. This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-jobs?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034) describes the process.

Comment: Well, for the first attempt I choose to use IoT Hub and an IoT Device that IoT Nodes can connect to it.
I used ESP32 Azure IoT Arduino and the generated connection string to connect to the IoT and noticed that the IoT Nodes can successfully send messages to the IoT Hub. But I couldn't find any documentation on how I can send notifications from IoT Hub to the connected Nodes.
I also create a Function App that triggered by GET request, but I could find a way to bind it with IoT Hub, so the hub can broadcast the received message from the webhook to all Nodes.

Comment: Excellent, that's the information I needed. To send a notification/command to all connected devices, you could use a job. A job can perform a Direct Method call to a device. This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-jobs) describes how to schedule a job and contains a snippet on how to schedule a job for all devices by using the `queryCondition`. You can create a job using the Service SDK ([C# sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/tree/master/iot-hub/Samples/service/JobsSample))

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It took a while to make Azure IoT Arduino working. Sadly, I found the details on Azure poorly documented. 
But now I am trying to make the connection between Azure Func and Azure IoT Hub. As I understood I need to use `ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString)` but not sure which connection string is needed. [Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/iotdev/understand-different-connection-strings-in-azure-iot-hub/) says I should endpoints that I can't find that in the portal.

Comment: For this you'll need the IoT Hub connection string. You can find it in the portal under Shared Access Policies, then clicking the policy with adequate rights (iothubowner will work fine for testing). It will have the connection string ready to copy.

Comment: Excellent, I updated the answer with the info from the comments. Please mark the answer as accepted so others can find it!