# Implementation of webhook consumer

Tags: http, webhooks, azure-iot-hub

I have an application that should be updated every time a certain event occurs in Azure IOT Hub. For this, azure uses webhooks and I need to enter a callback URL.

I am new to webhooks and reading into the implementation. If I understand correctly, the Azure IOT Hub is the webhook producer and my application is the webhook consumer.

Now, I'm able to find a lot of information on webhook producers but it's not clear to me what are the requirements on implementation of the webhook consumer. I have already created a classic Rest endpoint that should be called. Is this enough or should I follow a specific implementation protocol?

Comment: Can you add more details about your scenario? Do you want to update application or device? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65835672/azure-webhook-triggers-a-iot-hub if it helps

Comment: @AshokPeddakotla-MSFT I want to update an application based on data changed on the device